# Parsing file name with RegEx - Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, filenames

I'm trying to get the "real" name of a movie from its name when you download it.
So for instance, I have

```
Star.Wars.Episode.4.A.New.Hope.1977.1080p.BrRip.x264.BOKUTOX.YIFY
```

and would like to get

```
Star Wars Episode 4 A New Hope
```

So I'm using this regex:

```
.*?\d{1}?[ .a-zA-Z]*
```

which works fine, but only for a movie with a number, as in 'Iron Man 3' for example.
I'd like to be able to get movies like 'Interstellar' from

```
Interstellar.2014.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG
```

and I currently get

```
Interstellar 2
```

I tried several ways, and spent quite a lot of time on it already, but figured it wouldn't hurt asking you guys if you had any suggestion/idea/tip on how to do it...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: is that input format is fixed?

Comment: What about [`.*?\b(?=\.\d{4}\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/gV7nP6/2) (and then replacing `.` with space)? Is the year inforamtion always available?

Comment: But how do *you* distinguish between the date of the film and numbers in the title? What about `The Taking of Pelham 123`, `2001: A Space Odyssey`, or `Blues Brothers 2000`? Unless you can clearly outline an *"algorithm"* for doing that, how can you write a regex for it?

Comment: jonrsharpe that IS an interesting comment, I didn't think about that... Now I don't know how I'm gonna do ahah

Answer (score 0):

Given your examples and assuming you always download in *1080p* (or know that field's value):

```
x = 'Interstellar.2014.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG'
y = x.split('.')
print " ".join(y[:y.index('1080p')-1])
```

Forget the regex (for now anyway!) and work with the fixed field layout. Find a field you know (1080p) and remove the information you don't want (the year). Recombine the results and you get "Interstellar" and "Star Wars Episode 4 A New Hope".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, there is always a four-digit-year, or a four-digit-resolution notation within the movie's file name, a simple solution replaces the not-wanted parts as this:

> "(?:\.|\d{4,4}.+$)"

by a blank, strip()'ing them afterwards ...

For example:

```
    test1 = "Star.Wars.Episode.4.A.New.Hope.1977.1080p.BrRip.x264.BOKUTOX.YIFY"
    test2 = "Interstellar.2014.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG"

    res1 = re.sub(r"(?:\.|\d{4,4}.+$)",' ',test1).strip()
    res2 = re.sub(r"(?:\.|\d{4,4}.+$)",' ',test2).strip()

    print(res1, res2, sep='\n')


>>> Star Wars Episode 4 A New Hope
>>> Interstellar
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex would work (assuming the format is something like `moviename.year.1080p.anything` or `moviename.year.720p.anything`:

```
.*(?=.\d{4}.*\d{3,}p)
```

[Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/eJ8fE4/1#python) (try the unit tests to see the regex in action)

**Explanation:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

```
\.(?=.*?(?:19|20)\d{2}\b)|(?:19|20)\d{2}\b.*$
```

Try this with `re.sub`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/10

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\.(?=.*?(?:19|20)\d{2}\b)|(?:19|20)\d{2}\b.*$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "Star.Wars.Episode.4.A.New.Hope.1977.1080p.BrRip.x264.BOKUTOX.YIFY\nInterstellar.2014.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG\nIron Man 3"
subst = " "

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```